# Dropbox API error "A file with that name already exists at path"

Tags: excel, python-2.7, dropbox-api

I'm trying to go through a series of folders in dropbox containing excel workbooks.
I'm currently trying to use the [dropbox api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs) to find the file and download it as an input file in a local folder so I can parse the cells for the specific info I'm trying to get, delete the temp input file and then go to the next folder in dropbox to grab the next input file.

The program fails on the first input file with an error that says:

```
ErrorResponse: [403] u"A file with that name already exists at path
```

but there isn't any file in the folder when I go to check it.

```
conn = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(sess)
folder_metadata = conn.metadata("/Apps/Attachments")   #Base folder where folders with input files are located

#Go through each folder
for item in folder_metadata["contents"]:
    temp_path = item["path"]
    print temp_path

    #Download file called '2014.xlsx' and save it in a local folder as 'input.xlsx'
    conn.file_copy(temp_path + "/2014.xlsx", "/Users/myusername/Desktop/DropboxAPI/input.xlsx")

    #Code that parses through input.xlsx

    os.remove("input.xlsx")
```

Anyone have any similar problems? I'm programming on a Mac OS X (10.9.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling [`file_copy`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.file_copy), which copies a file in Dropbox to a different location (in Dropbox). I think what you want is to download the file to your local computer. For that, you should use [`get_file`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.get_file).

Something like this:

```
with file('/Users/myusername/Desktop/DropboxAPI/input.xlsx', 'wb') as fout:
    with conn.get_file(temp_path) as fin:
        fout.write(fin.read())
```